# Не правильное поведение bottom app bar

Tags: android, material-ui

У меня есть MainActivity c bottom app bar

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:hideOnScroll="true"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
    />
```

И два фрагмента

Первый

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/root_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Второй

```
     какой-та код
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width=«match_parent»
    android:layout_height=«match_parent»
    >
тоже какой-та код
   </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Проблема:
Если с первого фрагмента перейти на второй и прокрутить вниз, bottom app bar скроется, затем перейти обратно с пустым recycler view то скроллом bottom app bar уже не вернуть на вверх

[Пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXIbonsk1WY&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел метод

```
bottomAppBar.performHide();

bottomAppBar.performShow();
```